# spawn X threads per second in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I wanna achieve spawning 1000 threads per second. This is how I am doing it now :

```
public class Client {

    private static final int NTHREDS = 1000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

            Runnable worker = new MyTask();
            executor.execute(worker);

        }

        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");

    }

}
```

MyTask looks like this:

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        execute();
    }

}
```

In my example, the spawning doesnt happen per second, its just a for loop which sequentially spawns 1000 threads. Is there a better way to achieve X threads / second ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You might want to perform 1000 tasks per second, but you simply don't have that many CPUs and having too many threads will hurt performance.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to stress test something, but I'd imagine the ability of creating X threads / second would most likely depend a lot on the hardware.

Comment: Well, more than 1000 tasks / second, just wanted to know if this is the right way to do X tasks / second.. Is there a more accurate way ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the thread generation in timer or alike. E.g.

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NTHREDS);
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
            executor.execute(new MyTask());
        }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: +1 because ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor works with nano seconds internally.